# How to handle the vector pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Handling the pointer in a vector is new to me

I want to compare each character is weather **","** or not but unable to find it.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void parseInts(string str) {
vector<int> v;
string s;
for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
  if(str[i]!=",")
  cout<<str[i];
  else
  cout<<"\n";
}
 }

int main() {
string str;
cin >> str;
parseInts(str);

return 0;
}
```

Here's the error ->

> solution.cc: In function ‘void parseInts(std::__cxx11::string)’:
>
> solution.cc:12:18: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer
>
> and integer [-fpermissive]
>          if(str[i]!=",")

Comment: I can't see any pointer in vector here. The actual problem seems to be `if(str[i]!=",")` : Comparing a const char * with character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you can't compare a `const char*` with a `char`. So to fix this you should enclose the `,` in single quotes which means a `char` and not in double quotes because that means `const char*` which is the pointer to the first character in the double quotation. See the fix below.

```
void parseInts(string str) {
vector<int> v; // What do you mean by this? It's unused. You can' remove it.
string s;
for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
  if(str[i]!=',') // Should be single quotes and not double quotes
  cout<<str[i];
  else
  cout<<"\n";
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler gives you a pretty detailed warning:

**warning** comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [**-Waddress**]
   `if(str[i]!=",")` when you compile with the `-Wall` flag

string literal in this case `","`

By changing the comparison between `str[i]` (which is a `char`) and the comma character `char comma = ','` the code compiled and upon execution returned `foo\nbar` with test input `foo,bar`

```
...
char comma = ',';
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  // previously str[i] != ","; 
  if(str[i] != comma)      
    cout<<str[i];
  else
    cout<<"\n";
}
...
```